# Having problems getting LAMP installed

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

Okay, this is like my fifth time trying to get LAMP set up on Ubuntu, and yes, that includes using XAMPP. (All I want to do is practice my PHP so I can write WordPress plugins! *sob* Why does the world's easiest language have to be so hard to set up?)

*cough* Anyway. I used [these instructions](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-ubuntu.html) this time, after uninstalling XAMPP and what were hopefully all traces of my last attempt at doing this. I'm not using Netbeans -- gedit is okay with me -- and I didn't get any error messages or anything, so I thought I'd actually gotten it set up and set to use /home/feathertail/PHP as the document root.

I put a test file in there, browsed to /localhost and got this:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /testphp.php on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Can anyone point me in the direction of finally solving this once and for all?

Comment: as a test if you set the permissions on that directory to 777, does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

To solve this port problem in Linux, go inside the `/etc/apache2` folder and there is file **ports.conf**. Open this in a text editor and you see something like:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

so we have to change listen column and make it

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 8888
```

to do this, open a terminal and use these command

```
cd /etc/apache2 
etc/apache2:#sudo nano ports.conf
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, open it in terminal editor in which you just select listen column and change **80** to **8888**
like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 8888
```

and save it by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then press <kbd>Y</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
now run your apache it will start successfully, it really works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how did you install files but try to install these files for LAMP

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Basically nothing need to change (default root: /var/www). but if you want to change root directory then first create your directory.

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

change Document Root in 4th line. default is /var/www just change to your desire directory.
File will be looked like this

```
DocumentRoot your_DIR
```

Now logout and login. Your system is ready [apache, mysql-server, php, php-mysql]. You can install additional application phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

start phpmyadmin: go to firefox : localhost/phpmyadmin.

Comment: To add php in netbeans go to plugin in netbeans and search for php and install.

Comment: The step that I'm having trouble with is changing the document root. Apache works just fine on the default, and so does phpmyadmin. But when I change the document root to /home/feathertail/PHP, I get 403 Forbidden errors when I try to access it.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /home/feathertail/PHP   :place file on this dir and link will be http://localhost/page.php

Comment: will you please upload this file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Comment: Please don't chmod 777 anything without thinking it through. chmod a+x /home/feathertail ; chmod a+rx /home/feathertail/PHP should be enough to get rid of the 403.